# When calling a ASP.NET Web Service that generates an XML document, why does it take twice as long to get result after called the first time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, performance

I have a method in a web service I am writing that compiles a list of Performance Counter Categories,Instances, and Counters on that System.  It builds a xml document and returns that.  The first time the method is called after being published to the server, it takes about 17 seconds to get a result.  Each time it is called after that, it takes 38 seconds.  If I republish, the first time after that takes 17 seconds and then I am back at 38 seconds per a call.

```
    [WebMethod(Description="Returns the CounterList in XML Format")]
    public XmlDocument GetCounters()
    {
        XmlDocument CounterList = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = CounterList.CreateElement("CounterList");
        PerformanceCounterCategory[] pcc = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
        foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory cat in pcc)
        {
            XmlElement Category = CounterList.CreateElement("Category");
            XmlAttribute CatName = CounterList.CreateAttribute("Name");
            CatName.Value = cat.CategoryName;
            Category.Attributes.Append(CatName);
            String[] instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();
            PerformanceCounter[] pc;
            if (instances.Length > 0)
            {
                pc = cat.GetCounters(instances[0]);
                XmlElement Instances = CounterList.CreateElement("Instances");
                foreach (String instance in instances)
                {
                    XmlElement Instance = CounterList.CreateElement("Instance");
                    Instance.AppendChild(CounterList.CreateTextNode(instance));
                    Instances.AppendChild(Instance);
                }
                Category.AppendChild(Instances);
            }
            else
                pc = cat.GetCounters();

            XmlElement Counters = CounterList.CreateElement("Counters");
            foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in pc)
            {
                XmlElement Counter = CounterList.CreateElement("Counter");
                Counter.AppendChild(CounterList.CreateTextNode(counter.CounterName));
                Counters.AppendChild(Counter);
            }
            Category.AppendChild(Counters);
            root.AppendChild(Category);
        }
        CounterList.AppendChild(root);
        return CounterList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would comment out this line:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory[] pcc = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
```

and see if the symptom persists.

Note, I tried the code as a regular function and the first one took about 4 seconds, subsequent executions took about .2 seconds.

Comment: I changed `PerformanceCounterCategory[] pcc = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();        foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory cat in pcc)` to `foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory cat in PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories())` ... other than that I don't see how I can remove that line from the code since the Category is needed to get a list of counters and instances...

Comment: True, if you remove that line your program will not work.  However, if all executions run at the same speed after that, then you will know it is something about that particular line or the lines that work on the data it collects.  If you still have the symptom that the first execution is quick and subsequent ones are slow, then you can ignore that area of the code and see if the architecture of the service is a problem.  You are trying to narrow the scope of the problem.

Comment: ok aparently `String[] instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();` and code relating to that is causing time to double. Out of the 3 PerformanceCounterCategory, Instances, and PerformanceCounter... I didn't expect Instances to be the issue. I'll post more later once I find a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) that `PerformanceCounter` implements `IDisposable`; it may be that these objects acquire some scare resources or create some locks, making subsequent requests slower.

Try calling `Dispose` for each of your `PerformanceCounter` objects once you're done with them.  Maybe if you clean these up right away instead of waiting for the GC to run, you'll have a more consistant speed across requests.

Comment: Tried running Dispose on each Performance Counter at the end of the foreach loop and  time was the same. Good thought though..probably should have been disposing those anyway.